# Add TabHost to ViewPager without using Fragments android

Tags: android

I want to add a tabhost to my viewpager, but without using Fragments. I have a normal activity with a ViewPager and TabHost object. How to merge them? I searched it but found the use of Fragments everywhere.

Comment: what is the problem using fragments

Comment: @Raghunandan Well I never used it and my app is ready, I have to add this feature only, so I can't start again using Fragments.

Comment: For that you can use **TabGroupActivty** but it may be complicated. So better to use Fragments. Or Make Base Activity and Extends all others to that Base Activity.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Can't it be possible in simple Activity?